# Why does "local" discard the return code of a command?

Tags: bash, shell, local

This Bash snippet works as expected:

```
$ fun1() { x=$(false); echo "exit code: $?"; }
$ fun1
exit code: 1
```

But this one, using `local`, does not as I would have expected:

```
$ fun2() { local x=$(false); echo "exit code: $?"; }
$ fun2
exit code: 0
```

Can anyone explain why does `local` discards the return code of the command?

Comment: See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-03/msg00007.html

Comment: Perhaps "discard" would be clearer than "sweep".

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The reason the code with `local` returns 0 is because `$?` "Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline." Thus `$?` is returning the success of `local`

You can fix this behavior by separating the declaration of `x` from the initialization of `x` like so:

```
$ fun() { local x; x=$(false); echo "exit code: $?"; }; fun
exit code: 1
```

Comment: For the record, the problem is discussed in the BashPitfalls wiki: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#local_varname.3D.24.28command.29

Comment: also covered by google-styleguide for bash: https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=Use_Local_Variables#Use_Local_Variables

Answer (score 6):

The return code of the `local` command obscures the return code of `false`

Comment: Yeah, I understand it, but local being a special keyword I would expect not to obscure it. I guess it was a false assumption.

Comment: It's not a "special keyword", it's a shell builtin. Even builtins have return values.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) can detect this problem ([SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155)).