# Return value of function when substituted into local variable

Tags: bash

Say I have the following two Bash scripts:

Version #1:

```
#!/bin/bash

function bar
{
  if true; then
    echo "error" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "bar"
}

function foo
{
  local val=`bar`
  echo $?
  echo "val: $val"
}

foo
```

With version #2 second having a slightly different `foo`:

```
function foo
{
  val=`bar` #note no 'local'
  echo $?
  echo "val: $val"
}
```

Version #1 gives me the following output:

```
error
0
val:
```

Whilst version #2 gives me this:

```
error
1
val:
```

The inclusion of `local` in #2 appears to hide the return value of `bar`.

Am I correct in thinking this is because `local` is itself a function, and is returning 0? And if so, is there a way around this and make `val` a local variable, but still test the return value of `bar`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [should local keyword sweep return code of command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421257/should-local-keyword-sweep-return-code-of-command)

Comment: @dogbane funny, I don't remember answering that one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are reading the return value of `local` which was successful.  The fix is to separate the variable declaration from its definition like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

function bar
{
  if true; then
    echo "error" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "bar"
}

function foo
{
  local val
  val=$(bar)
  echo $?
  echo "val: $val"
}

foo
```

#### Output

```
$ ./localtest
error
1
val:
```

Comment: Of course, stupid me! The simplest answers are the best, thanks.