# Bash 'local' variable giving strange behavior

Tags: bash

I originally coded something to fetch a file via `wget` like this:

```
local wget_output=$(wget -O "${TEMP_FILE}"  "$REQUEST_URL" 2>&1)
local wget_success=$?
if [[ $wget_success -eq 0 ]]; then
```

so that the 'then' clause would only execute if the `wget` was successful.  However, it executed every time (ie. when the requested file was not on the server.)  This code works functionally correct:

```
wget_output=$(wget -O "${TEMP_FILE}"  "$REQUEST_URL" 2>&1)
local wget_success=$?
if [[ $wget_success -eq 0 ]]; then
```

The only difference is the removal of the first `local`.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It's not that the variable is local, it's that you're declaring it local *on the same line*, so the exit status of `local`, rather than the exit status of your command substitution, is in `$?`. Give me a minute and I'll find a dupe for this one.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does “local” sweep the return code of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421257/why-does-local-sweep-the-return-code-of-a-command)

Comment: Declare your locals *before* you assign to them: `local wget_output; wget_output=$(wget ...)` will avoid this issue.

Comment: btw, as a stylistic matter, I'd consider `if wget_output=$(wget ...); then ...` rather than capturing `wget_success` at all. If you need to distinguish between specific error codes, by contrast, then you can capture `$?` in the `else` clause.

Comment: Sorry about the dupe - I was totally lost on this one and could not determine the correct search parameters!

Comment: @JoeG That's often a problem with bash. [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) would have pointed out [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155).

Comment: Installed ShellCheck, now officially in the toolbox - thank you!