# bash add git command result to local variable

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to change the name of my file, adding the number of commits and the current branch name on my file before sending it to the repository.

But I get the following error:

./publish_to_artifactory.sh: line 4: local: `rev-parse': not a valid identifier'`

```
upload() {
  local currentBranch=git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD;
  local gitNumberOfCommits=git rev-list --count HEAD;

  for file in ./../*.ipa; do
    mv $file mobile-${currentBranch}-${gitNumberOfCommits};
    echo "uploading zeos-mobile-$currentBranch-$gitNumberOfCommits";
    curl -X PUT -u $PUBLISH_USER:$PUBLISH_PASS -T mobile-$currentBranch-$gitNumberOfCommits; http://example.com/artifactory/ios-dev-local/ --fail
  done
}

upload;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't put command substitutions on the same line as `local` at all -- doing so shadows the exit status of those substitutions with the exit status of the `local` command.

Comment: Instead, run `local currentBranch gitNumberOfCommits` as one line, and then put `currentBranch=$(...)` and `gitNumberOfCommits=$(...)` each on a separate line. See [Why does `local` sweep the return code of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421257/why-does-local-sweep-the-return-code-of-a-command)

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and also fixing the various quoting bugs it identifies.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign the output of a command to a variable, you need to use command-substitution syntax in `bash`.

```
local currentBranch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
local gitNumberOfCommits="$(git rev-list --count HEAD)"
```

What you have done is stored the literal string in those local variables defined. When shell was tokenizing them to evaluate it has understood it as a variable assignment gone horribly wrong! What it understood is a `local` variable in the name of `currentBranch` set to a value `git` and tries to run `rev-list` as a command which it cannot obviously find in its list of standard paths (under `$PATH`)

Comment: Also, `local a=b c` means, in effect, `local a=b; local c`. Note that the result of expansion (`$(git rev-parse ...)`) won't re-expand here, so you could write `local currentBranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD)` even if `git rev-parse` might produce more than one word; but the double quotes are useful for our own sanity. :-) Finally, as Charles Duffy noted, if you want to check the *exit status* of a substitution, you have to separate it out from the `local` declaration.