# Bash array size not reflecting actual size when used with local builtin command

Tags: bash, sed

I have a log file `ala.txt` looking like that:

```
dummy FromEndPoint = PW | dummy | ToEndPoint = LALA | dummy
dummy FromEndPoint = PW | dummy | ToEndPoint = PAPA | dummy
dummy FromEndPoint = WF | dummy | ToEndPoint = LALA | dummy
dummy FromEndPoint = WF | dummy | ToEndPoint = KAKA | dummy
```

I used `sed` to generate an array containing every combination of FromEndPoint and ToEndPoint. Then I want to iterate through it.

```
function main {
    file="./ala.txt"
    local a=`sed 's/^.*FromEndPoint = \([a-zA-Z\-]*\).*ToEndPoint = \([a-zA-Z\-]*\).*$/\1;\2/' $file | sort -u`

    echo ${#a[@]} # prints 1

    for connectivity in ${a[@]}; do
        echo "conn: $connectivity" # iterates 4 times
        #conn: PW;LALA
        #conn: PW;PAPA
        #conn: WF;KAKA
        #conn: WF;LALA
    done

}
```

Why `echo ${#a[@]}` prints 1 if there are 4 elements in the array? How can I get a real size of it?

Bash used: 4.4.12(1)-release

Comment: `local a=\`cmd\`` is not a declaration of an array. `a` is just a string. It then undergoes word-splitting in the `for` loop resulting in 4 iterations.

Comment: `local -a a` and `local -A a` don't work neither.

Comment: `declare -p a` will show its definition. That will show you that it contains only one element, with spaces in it; *not* each space-separated piece in a different element.

Comment: Quoting your expansion, as in `for connectivity in "${a[@]}"; do`, would iterate one array element per run of the loop, not splitting on spaces (and expanding globs), and so would make the number of times your loop iterates consistent with the number of elements in your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use variables to store multi-line content, use arrays!

In a `bash` shell you could process substitution feature to make the command output appear as a file content for you to parse over with an array. in `bash` versions of `4` and above, commands [`readarray` and `mapfile`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) can parse the multi-line output given a delimiter without needing to use a for-loop with `read`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=()
while read -r unique; do
    array+=( "$unique" )
done< <(sed 's/^.*FromEndPoint = \([a-zA-Z\-]*\).*ToEndPoint = \([a-zA-Z\-]*\).*$/\1;\2/' file | sort -u)
```

Now printing the length of the array as `echo "${#array[@]}"` should print the length as expected.

And always separate the initialization of `local` variables and assigning of the values to it. See [Why does `local` sweep the return code of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421257/why-does-local-sweep-the-return-code-of-a-command)