# shell script "set -e" with readonly variable

Tags: bash, shell

This works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
V="$(cat non-existant-file)"
echo "var V: $V"
```

the script fails on line 3 and exits without executing line 4 thanks to the "set -e".

Now, small change:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
readonly V="$(cat non-existant-file)"
echo "var V: $V"
```

And now the script executes line 4.
Same behavior when running the script in `sh`.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: `set -e` is a not a reliable way of handling errors. See [BashFAQ/105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).  See [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30078281/6862601) for more details about proper error handling.

Comment: It's `#!`, not `!#`.

Comment: ...closely related: [why does `local` sweep the return code of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421257/why-does-local-sweep-the-return-code-of-a-command). I could have sworn we already had a duplicate for `readonly`, but it's not being trivial to find. (Update: Found it!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the line `readonly V="$(cat non-existant-file)"` is not a simple assignment: it is the composition of an assignment that fails, followed by the instruction `readonly V`, which succeeds.

That explains the behavior you observed, and this Bash pitfall is mentioned for a similar construct (`local`) in the documentation [BashFAQ/105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) indicated by @codeforester.

So, if you try instead the following code, you should observe the behavior you expect:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
V=$(cat non-existant-file)
readonly V
echo "var V: $V"
```

Minor remarks:

- I corrected the shebang that should be `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`, not `!#/bin/bash`
- I replaced `V="$(cat non-existant-file)"` with `V=$(cat non-existant-file)` because the quotes are unnecessary here.

Comment: I though it might be that. But I would expect the whole line to fail if either the assignment or the readonly instruction fails. Thanks!

Comment: @bruce_ricard indeed this fact is not obvious, so actually the thing to remember is: never write `local V=$(command)` nor `readonly V=$(command)` in presence of `set -e`, but rather split the compound instruction in 2 parts: `local V; V=$(command)` or respectively `V=$(command); readonly V`.