# Bash variable declaration vs assignment

Tags: bash, sh

The `declare` keyword is optional in bash, so `my_var="foobar"` is the same as `declare my_var="foobar"`. Does bash/dash actually assign new value to variable or it just declares new variable and hides existing variable with the same name?

```
#!/bin/sh

GetValue ()
{
    echo "foobar";
    return 1;
}

var1="$(GetValue)" && echo "Successed!" || echo "Failed!";  # Failed!
declare var2="$(GetValue)" && echo "Successed!" || echo "Failed!";  # Successed!
```

In the snippet above, although both variables were successfully declared and assigned, the use of `declare` makes a difference between the status code. Why?

Comment: [shellcheck/SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155) explains this exact case. A tip: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ (and better - its [editor integrations](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#user-content-in-your-editor)) to check script sanity, which is usually faster than typing a question here. (Note: I am not dissuading you from asking questions. Just introducing to a tool that I find quite useful.)

Comment: Despite its name, `declare` really is just used to set attributes on names or (with `-p`) display the value assigned to a name. If `var2` is undefined, it remains undefined after `declare var2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `GetValue` along with printing a string to stdout also returns a code `1`. So assignment to the variable `var1` from the function, though sets the value to `foobar`, sets an exit code `1` which is a non-zero code causing the part after the `||` to be invoked.

But remember the *same* happens in the case with the `declare`, but the reason you see `Successed` is because the exit code `1` from the function is suppressed when the `declare` built-in acts on the variable. So

```
var2="$(GetValue)"  # sets a non-zero exit code 1
declare var2        # sets a success exit code 0
```

Since the *last* foreground command's exit code is the one used in the evaluation of success/failure, the part after `&&`, which is `echo "Successed!"` gets invoked.

So, your claim of using `declare` in the variable assignment makes a difference in the exit code is incorrect, because these two still remain the same as they both set the exit code `1` which triggers the false case.

```
var1="$(GetValue)" && echo "Successed!" || echo "Failed!";
var2="$(GetValue)" && echo "Successed!" || echo "Failed!";
```

Suggest to always *separate* the initialization/declaration when using the built-ins `local`, `declare` and `export`

```
var=5
declare -i var
```

is preferred over `declare -i var=5`.

See [Why does `local`/`declare` sweep the return code of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421257/why-does-local-sweep-the-return-code-of-a-command) for more reference on the subject.